# df.apply() but skip the first row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply the following df.apply command to a dataframe but want it to skip the first row. Any advice on how to do that without setting the first row as the column headers?

```
res = sheet1[sheet1.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('TRUE', case=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

Comment: use iloc if you want to specify rows. Specifically, sheet[sheet1.iloc[1:, :].apply()]

Comment: Do you simply want a series as the output (and don't care if its index is dropped and output uses integers as index), or do you want to reassign that result back into the dataframe (i.e. preserve the original index)?

Answer (score 0):

You can select from the index one and on as follow:

```py
res = sheet1[1:].apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('TRUE', case=False).any(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT Version 3:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,11), 'b':range(2,21,2), 'c':range(1,20,2),
    'd':['TRUE' if random.randint(0,1) else 'FALSE' for _ in range(10)]})
print (df)


res = df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('TRUE', case=False).any(), axis=1)]

print (res.loc[1:])
```

If all you want to do is to get only the rows from 1 onwards, you can just do it as shown above:

The input Dataframe is:

```
    a   b   c      d
0   1   2   1   TRUE
1   2   4   3  FALSE
2   3   6   5  FALSE
3   4   8   7   TRUE
4   5  10   9   TRUE
5   6  12  11   TRUE
6   7  14  13  FALSE
7   8  16  15  FALSE
8   9  18  17   TRUE
9  10  20  19   TRUE
```

The output of res will be:

```
    a   b   c     d
0   1   2   1  TRUE
3   4   8   7  TRUE
4   5  10   9  TRUE
5   6  12  11  TRUE
8   9  18  17  TRUE
9  10  20  19  TRUE
```

The output of res[1:] - excluding first row will be:

```
    a   b   c     d
3   4   8   7  TRUE
4   5  10   9  TRUE
5   6  12  11  TRUE
8   9  18  17  TRUE
9  10  20  19  TRUE
```

## EDIT Version 2:

Here's an example with `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` in the column.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['TRUE' if random.randint(0,1) else 'FALSE' for _ in range(10)]})
print (df)

res = df.iloc[1:].apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('TRUE', case=False).any(), axis=1)

print (res)
```

The output will be:

Original DataFrame:

```
       a
0   TRUE
1   TRUE
2  FALSE
3  FALSE
4  FALSE
5   TRUE
6   TRUE
7  FALSE
8  FALSE
9  FALSE
```

Result from the DataFrame:

```
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

You can also give loc instead of iloc:

```
res = df.loc[1:].apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('TRUE', case=False).any(), axis=1)
```

As you can see, it skipped the first row.

## Old answer

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,11), 'b':range(2,21,2), 'c':range(1,20,2)})
print (df)

res = df.iloc[1:,:].apply(lambda x: x+10,axis=1)
print (res)
```

Original DataFrame:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   1
1   2   4   3
2   3   6   5
3   4   8   7
4   5  10   9
5   6  12  11
6   7  14  13
7   8  16  15
8   9  18  17
9  10  20  19
```

Only rows 1 onwards got modified:

```
    a   b   c
1  12  14  13
2  13  16  15
3  14  18  17
4  15  20  19
5  16  22  21
6  17  24  23
7  18  26  25
8  19  28  27
9  20  30  29
```

Comment: I tried that but keep getting "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)." as an error. This was my line     res = sheet1[sheet1.iloc[1:].apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('TRUE', case=False).any(), axis=1)]

Comment: Do you want to subset of this data back into res or just the boolean of it?